# DateTime.TryParseExact CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong, I'm trying to parse the date to ensure its a valid date, if so convert it to the format I require.

I have tried different ways of doing this, but all return `01/01/0001 00:00:00`.

value of string `parseArrivalDate` = `02/02/2013`

```
DateTime ukDateFormat;
string ukFormat = "0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy";    
DateTime.TryParseExact(parseArrivalDate, ukFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out ukDateFormat);    
DateTime test = ukDateFormat;
```

-------------------------------------EDIT-------------------------------

OK sorry, I did not explain it very well. If I enter UK format say 27/02/2013, and when I had UK format as dd/MM/yyyy it worked ok, problem was when I was entering US or any other format, it was returning the incorrect date, so I was changing the format round thinking that was the problem.

It has now dawned on me after reading your comments, that I had the uk format correct 1st time, so my problem is, how can I change the code, so that any date format can be parsed correctly.

Hope that makes more sense
Thanks

Comment: what is the result of TryParse? how would it work if you only pass parseArrivalDate and ukFormat ?

Answer (score 7):

Your string

```
"0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy"
```

has a number `0`, a colon `:`, and a format corresponding to

```
"Wed, Mar 27, 2013"
```

for example, if the culture is `"en-GB"` ("English (United Kingdom)"). It probably comes from a `String.Format`, `Console.WriteLine` or similar method call, where it is put into braces `{}` to format a text, as in

```
Console.WriteLine("The date {0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy} was selected.", someDateTime);
```

It would work with code like:

```
string arrivalDateString = "Wed, Mar 27, 2013";

...

DateTime result;
string yourFormat = "ddd, MMM d, yyyy";    // no "0:" part
bool isOK = DateTime.TryParseExact(arrivalDateString, yourFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result);    
if (isOK)
{
    // Worked! Answer is in 'result' variable
}
else
{
    // Didn't work! 'result' variable holds midnight 1 January 0001
}
```

---

The format that corresponds to `"27/03/2013"` is `"dd/MM/yyyy"` (or `"d/M/yyyy"`). The format that corresponds to `"03/27/2013"` is `"MM/dd/yyyy"` (or `"M/d/yyyy"`).

It is not possible to have one method that handles both styles of dates, since a string like

```
"01/04/2013"   /* ambiguous */
```

could mean either

- 1 April 2013
- January 4, 2013

so it's ambiguous, and there's no way we can tell what date is meant. See also [Wikipedia: Calendar date → Date format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_date#Date_format).

Answer (score 1):

your date string is: `02/02/2013` and the format you are using is `"0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy"` which is wrong, it should be `MM/dd/yyyy` if its month first.

```
DateTime ukDateFormat;
string ukFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";    
DateTime.TryParseExact(parseArrivalDate, ukFormat,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None, out ukDateFormat);    
 DateTime test = ukDateFormat;
```

If the date you have specified contains day first then month, then use the format `"dd/MM/yyyy"`, By the way you can using single `d` and `M` for both single digit and double digits day/month.

Currently you are getting the `DateTime.MinValue`, since parsing is failing because of the invalid format.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you expect, but your input string does not met your `ukFormat` pattern! So it's totally right behavior.

Change your pattern to `""dd/MM/yyyy""` to make `TryParseExact` work.

Answer (score 1):

Your provided format looks a little strange. Try to replace it with this

```
string ukFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
```

And read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) on this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for helping me understand where I was going wrong, the code below is what I have came up with although not perfect as 03/06/2013 UK is different than the meaning of 03/06/2013 US.

I have added text above the text box asking people to use format dd/mm/yyyy.

```
string getArrivalDate   = ArrivalDate;
                    string getDepartureDate = DepartureDate;

                    string dteFormat        = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                    DateTime result;
                    string arrivalDateParse;
                    string departureDateParse;

                    bool arrival = DateTime.TryParseExact(getArrivalDate, dteFormat, new CultureInfo("en-GB"), DateTimeStyles.None, out result);
                    if (arrival)
                        {
                        arrivalDateParse = getArrivalDate;
                        }
                    else
                        {
                        arrivalDateParse = "notvalid";
                        }

                    bool depart = DateTime.TryParseExact(getDepartureDate, dteFormat, new CultureInfo("en-GB"), DateTimeStyles.None, out result);
                    if (depart)
                        {
                        departureDateParse = getDepartureDate;
                        }
                    else
                        {
                        departureDateParse = "notvalid";
                        }

                    if (arrivalDateParse == "notvalid" || departureDateParse == "notvalid")
                        {
                        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                            {
                            return Json(new { Confirm = "Date not in correct format" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                            }
                        else
                            {
                            TempData["Error"] = "Sorry your arrival date or departure date is not a valid format, please enter date as dd/mm/yyyy example 02/12/2013";

                            return View("~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml");
                            }
```

If anyone can improve on the code, it would be appreciated.

Thanks

George

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using InvariantCulture for this consider using RoundTrip style (ISO-8601).  See this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882584.aspx